# Geo-target a website to rank in both the USA and UK

Tags: google-search-console, language, geolocation

Can anyone tell me if it is possible for Google to index a webpage for search results in the USA and UK.

The geo targeting is currently set to the USA. I have read the following Google guide https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

But was not clear on if i need to create a .en-uk version of the page or not.

Comment: You can't set the geo-target to two different countries at once.   However, you can remove geo-targeting and will rank globally.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. This is most likely your scenario:

> Your content has small regional variations with similar content in a single language. For example, you might have English-language content targeted to the US, GB, and Ireland.

You definitely need to publish the same pages slightly modified to the UK version, for example words in American English with 'z' vs words in British English with 's'.

Take into account that these meta location tags are speakers-region based (en-us = English speakers in the United states).

Even if you have the content on a different domain (.co.uk) you need to implement this approach.

Comment: I have removed the geo targeting and added the  hreflang tag <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/" hreflang="en" /> to target all english speakers. Would you suggest the geo specific tags over this solution?

Comment: @D.Wheatley  you should be able to rank outside your geo-target region now. This solution is better, but Does your website has ccTLD? if it does I would suggest creating a 'en-us' and 'en-uk' versions of the website, which in my opinion is the best implementation for hreflang

Comment: I do not have a ccTLD

Comment: @D.Wheatley how did you go?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, USA-based websites can index and rank in the UK (or any other country). For instance, if you search for the brand name of an American-only company, chances are it will rank highly in the US, UK, and elsewhere in the world. But outside of a few exceptions like branded terms or some informational terms, it is really hard for the same page to rank in multiple countries and perform well. This is because so many types of searches have geo-specific relevancy (i.e. if you are searching for a product to buy, you'll more often than not want to buy from a company in the same country as you because shipping and other logistics will be easier to handle). So, if you are really wanting to get your website performing highly in the UK search results, it would be worth getting the UK TLD and building out a UK website (along with, more than likely, a UK arm of your business).

Comment: It won't rank around the world if the geo-targeting has been set in Google Search Console.